# Not able to hit an endpoint with variable in Postman

Tags: collections, postman

When using an endpoint I am able to get the request done successfully and retrieve the response as well  but when I use the variable in my endpoint for example: {{abc}}/api/user/id it gives status 404 not found and I have specified the variable in the collection "abc"
so not sure why is this issue is coming. Why the variable is not recognizable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you hover over that variable are you able to see the value ? are using data file?

Comment: @PDHide Yes I am able to see the url when I hover over

Comment: Do you have any environment variable or local variable or data variable with same name ?  These have more preference than collection so if you have same variable name then this values will over ride the collection variable value

Comment: @PDHide thanks this solves my issue

Comment: Added as an answer could you please uvote and accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any environment variable or local variable or data variable with same name ? These have more preference than collection so if you have same variable name then this values will over ride the collection variable value

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-scopes

[image]

### In postman **precedence** is from down to bottom and **scope** is from top to bottom

**Scope:**

Meaning if you have global variable defined then it will be visible for all collections and environment variable will be visible only for that particular environment.

**Precedence**

if you have a variable with same name defined in both environment and collection then the value will be taken from **environment**. as precedence is collection < environment